# Why dont I get a lexical this on vscode typescript files when declaring functions in objects?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, this

In the typescript playground, whenever I declare an object with a function property, the lexical `this` is inferred as the parent object. See example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gKBpmUCm0Bc2ATgK44A0GWEIAtjgGJgAUAlKlVllABYCWEAHS5onGAF804oA

However, in VSCode, for whatever reason, I do not get a lexical this unless I explicitly declare the `this` for that function on a pre-declared type. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen? VSCode is latest, version is `4.3.5`

***Note: this only happens with OBJECTS; classes work fine.***

[image: no type inferred on lexical this]
[image: no auto complete on the lexical this]

Answer (score 0):

This required `"noImplicitThis": true,` in tsconfig.json